# View's toolbar and menu missing when reopening a workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, e4

I am writing a plugin for eclipse and want to use the e4-model fragment definition to add a toolbar and menu to the plugin's primary view. When the plugin is initially opened (for the first time within a workspace), both toolbar and menu are show.
However, on any subsequent opening of the same workspace, the view is shown, but the toolbar and menu are both missing.

[image]

On the extension point, I tried applying the fragment on "always", "initial" and "notexists", but nothing solved the issue.

I suspect that the caching mechanisms of the plugin elements somehow corrupt my local environment in such a way, that the view is not recreated every time the view is loaded. Has anybody experienced a similar effect?

Is there any way to programatically purge any remaining ui fragments, and reinitialize the entire model created by a single plugin?
Is there a way to "step through" the initialization process of the model fragments to observe the creation process (I am thinking of something similar to a breakpoint on the plugin definition)?

Comment: The `-clearPersistedState` argument discards any persisted model and starts from scratch on each run.

Comment: Can this be set for the plugin, or just for the debug configuration? Because it's not just a problem in debug mode. It persists, when I export the plugin and use it in a live workspace. I can't ask the users to reinitialize the entire workspace on every restart. :(

Comment: This is global. The persisted state it refers to is only the UI design in the e4xmi files.

Comment: The persisted model is stored in the workspace .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi file.

Comment: I looked into the workbench.xmi, but the model seems valid. It is not obviously corrupted, in some way, which is why I don't understand the missing DirectToolItems. They are listed individually and should be appended. I think I need to debug the process of them being appended into the live model.